# SQL count results on left join

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I'm trying to get the total count of a table from a left join where there's a multiple of the same id. Here's my example below -

Table 1:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| project_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| token       | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status      | char(1)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| permissions | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created     | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created    | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified   | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active     | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have this statement so far -

```
SELECT account_id, (SELECT COUNT(invitations.id)
    FROM invitations WHERE invitations.project_id = projects.id) AS inv_count
FROM projects order by account_id;
```

And here's a sample of the results:

```
+------------+-----------+
| account_id | inv_count |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         0 |
|          2 |         2 |
|          2 |         0 |
|          3 |         4 |
|          3 |         0 |
|          3 |         4 |
|          3 |         0 |
|          4 |         6 |
|          4 |         3 |
|          4 |         3 |
|          4 |         5 |
|          4 |         3 |
|          4 |         9 |
|          5 |         6 |
|          5 |         0 |
|          5 |         4 |
|          5 |         2 |
|          5 |         2 |
```

How do I get account_id to show once and the sum of inv_count to show as 1 line? So I should see -

```
+------------+-----------+
| account_id | inv_count |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         0 |
|          2 |         2 |
|          3 |         8 |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to put your query in a derived table (and name it, say `tmp`) and then group by the `account_id`:

```
SELECT account_id,
       SUM(inv_count) AS inv_count
FROM
  ( SELECT account_id, 
           (SELECT COUNT(invitations.id)
            FROM invitations 
            WHERE invitations.project_id = projects.id
           ) AS inv_count
    FROM projects 
  ) AS tmp
GROUP BY account_id
ORDER BY account_id ;
```

To simplify it farther, you can convert the inline subquery to a `LEFT` join. This way, no derived table is needed. I've also added aliases and removed the `ORDER BY`. MySQL does an implicit `ORDER BY` when you have `GROUP BY` so it's not needed here (unless you want to order by some other expression, different from the one you group by):

```
SELECT 
    p.account_id,
    COUNT(i.id) AS inv_count 
FROM 
    projects AS p 
  LEFT JOIN 
    invitations AS i
      ON i.project_id = p.id
GROUP BY 
    p.account_id ;
```

Comment: amazing, that works. fyi- not some scrub who doesnt research, etc. been trying different things for a few hours to try and get it. thanks again. can you explain what's happening here by any chance?